# Multiple stacked DC-DC converters

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck

I am trying to minimze the output voltage ripple of a 4-layer pcb power supply and am curious as to what approach would be better.  So I have 6 low voltage high amp buck converters feeding 6 chips.  The buck converters will all have the same frequency, characteristics and output voltage.  The chips are all the same as well.  My original idea was to have have a power plane, with 6 splits, each one unique to each chip, like below;

```
              (top view)
              buck Vout----------> cpu
              break
              buck Vout----------> cpu
              break
              .....
```

They would all share the same ground plane.  Now I'm wondering if I should keep the voltage plane unbroken?  This should make sure the cpus are running at the same voltage, but would the control circuitry of the bucks interfere with each other?

Comment: If voltages are same....is there any specific advantage of using 6 converters separately when u r generating same voltage. How much are the currents for each buck.....I prefer to use multi phase Buck converters like ( ex:LTC3829,LTC3880), they will have less EMI(if u use same voltage same frequency regulators there are high chances of EMI), less ripple, very good transient response.. there are very good app notes from TI and linear like "http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt449/slyt449.pdf"

Comment: Each Buck will be supplying ~40 amps for a total system load of 240 A at .90V for a string of FPGAs.  I chose the TPS53819A as a trade off between cost/complexity/time.  Also I am new to power supply design, the LTC3880 looks interesting.  I'm confused though on much current it can drive, or is this based on my selection of the mosfets?  I thought the driver had a limit, but the datasheet doesn't specify anything.  At 240 amps can that one controller support the whole load?

Comment: i don't know the current requirements previously. LTC3880 may not be sufficient. 240A is huge current. there are few controllers from TI,Lienar,infineon etc like LTC3731. But i strongly recommend to contact these companies and get possible options. If you are new to Power supply design, doing such a high current low voltage power supply is little tough task. i don't want to discourage you....but try to take as much help from manufacturers and Tools which they give. Layout is very very critical....going to multiple buck converters and paralling them is definitely bad idea for 240A......

Comment: Actual current taken load of Buck will go through the MOSFETs. so, mostly current limit is decided by their characterstics and controller IC will have one mechanism for Current limiting. maximum current to be taken from Buck controller will depend on these things

Comment: Thanks. I suppose until I get a new design I will keep them on separate planes.  I went through every TI buck controller and datasheets and their evm guides for each one until I decided on the one above.  A more complex design is a must for the higher current situations.  For now what I have is the FPGAs in the middle of the board 2x3 with 3 regulators on the left and 3 regulators on the right, each on their own voltage plane.  I think I will eventually switch to the LM3754, but it has no voltage control.